# Чтение содержимого папки в Node.js

Tags: node.js

Как вывести содержимое папки C:\Users в Node.js (При этом файл с кодом находится на рабочем столе)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если синхронные вызовы допустимы, можно при помощи [`fs.readdirSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options).

```js
const dirPath = 'C:\\Users';
const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath).map(fileName => `${dirPath}\\${fileName}`);
console.log(files.join('\n'));
```